# how do i get this json data from php server in android

Tags: php, android, json

how do i get this json data in android 
this data is in localhost. I must fetch this data using URL and display in listview in android.Can any one help in coding plz

```
[

    {
    "id":"111114",
    "name":"Prandar"
    },
    {
    "id":"111115",
    "name":"Catmilkend"
    },
    {
    "id":"111110",
    "name":"Allan"
    },
    {
    "id":"111111",
    "name":"Aircornal"
    },
    {
    "id":"111112",
    "name":"Allaxander"
    },
    {
    "id":"111113",
    "name":"AppleMacro"
    }
]
```

Comment: i cant change the json format. I must used this same format can u help me different coding

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common need, but involves several independent steps which could easily be their own StackOverflow question.

1) in a file named info.php you will create the JSON string to return to requests:

```
<?php

    // this may come from a database
    $info = array ('id'  => '101',
                   'name'=> 'bill'
              )
    echo json_encode($info); // returns {"id":'101',"name": "bill"}
?>
```

2) Send a http GET request to myserver.com/info.php and capture the string response.
http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/

3) Then parse the JSON into objects or dictionary array with a JSON framework.
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_JSON_Parser_Example

4) Use a ListView in Android to display it.
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: where will i created a info.php

Comment: where can i find the info.php

Comment: sir i cant change the json format. I must used this same format can u help me different coding