# How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView from PHP server to Android

Tags: android, listview, imagedownload

I am new to android & exploring it.I need to load image of User dynamically in my list shown below

[list of Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCRvV.png)!

I use one static image to show as user image from my resource folder. this list is dynamic & get change as my location get change but only when i refresh it.

```
AddObjectToList(jFan_Data.getString("uniqid").toString(),R.drawable.ic_add, jFan_Data.getString("name"), jFan_Data.getString("distance"));
```

on click of the list item need to display the complete profile of user. i succeed to show complete profile on click i need to show image of user here as well

[user_profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfTLQ.png)!

How i get the data from php(Please gone through) -> [android List View having jsonObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458198/android-list-view-having-jsonobject)

now how i get images of users from my php server...  would greatly appreciate any sample code,scripts, and pointers to where I could find more information to better understand the inner working. Also, pretty much interested to know how i use other framework or is there are better frameworks to do what I want to, I am happy to learn about that!!!

Comment: This might help. [Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012) [Lazy list](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Comment: Both your questions have been answered on this site. 
Get data from php server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416132/how-do-i-get-this-json-data-from-php-server-in-android
Lazy loading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912054/lazy-load-images-on-listview-in-androidbeginner-level.

Comment: Tanks a lot @THelper [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)! worked thanks again for your valuable respons!!! :)